# Изменить поле в listview wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Добавляю значение в `listview` так :

```
this.listView.Items.Add(new MyItem { Name = info[0], Done = "false" });
```

где

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Done { get; set; }
}
```

в xaml

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name, StringFormat={}{0:C}}"></GridViewColumn>
<GridViewColumn Header="Done" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Done, StringFormat={}{0:C}}"></GridViewColumn>
```

Возник вопрос, как изменить значение `Done` у выделенной строки ?

Пытался как так, но безуспешно

```
Type t = typeof(MyItem);
var m = (MyItem)Convert.ChangeType(listView.SelectedItem, t);

m.Done = "true";
listView.SelectedItem = m;
```

Comment: Почему вы храните логическое значение в строке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш `MyItem` никак не оповещает заинтересованных лиц об изменениях, поэтому нужно обновлять вручную:

```
listView.Items.Refresh();
```

Comment: да, спасибо большое